# Can't Install WordPress (local) Failed to open file wp-includes/wp-db.php

Tags: database, wpdb, installation, wp-config, filesystem

Title kinda says it all. Trying to install WP locally and I get the following error when trying to use the `wp-config.php` generator UI:

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or
>   directory in /www/sites/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1487
>
> Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in
>   /www/sites/wordpress/wp-includes/wp-db.php on line 1513

Followed by the traditional `Error establishing a database connection` page.

So, fun fact...that file is totally there. I've even `chmod -R 777 /www/sites/wordpress`, so it's not a permissions issue either! Has anyone else ever come across this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock

Comment: Confirm that var/mysql/mysql.sock is exist while you getting error?

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd It is not there! In fact, `which mysql` doesn't respond with anything - however I can confirm that MySQL is installed and running using OS X' system prefs.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I don't see how that could be my problem...localhost maps just fine when I try to connect using a MySQL client...